# Email go to spam i don't know how to fix it

Tags: javascript, php

i have a problem of once the visitor of my site fill the contact, i receive  the email in the spam folder of my gmail, i look on internet and i find that i need to add question and answer code like this [quiz math-quiz "20+12=?|32"]

so how i can add this to book.php files you will find below the all code of the page

pleas help

```
$title = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES));
$fname = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['fname'], ENT_QUOTES));
$lname = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['lname'], ENT_QUOTES));
$phone = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['phone'], ENT_QUOTES));
$country = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['country'], ENT_QUOTES));
$city = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['city'], ENT_QUOTES));
$address = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES));
$email = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES));
$message = stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES));

if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',str_replace('&amp;','&',$email))) {

{
    
$to="Exemplemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "- $fname ";
        
        $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $header .= "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n";
            
            $body = "
                            
                <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
                    <style type='text/css'>
                        .css { heigh:20px; family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; size: 12px; }
                        hr.style {border-top: 1px dashed #e5e5e5;border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;}
                    </style>        
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        
            <div class='css'>- Title :<b> $title </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- First Name :<b> $fname </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- Last Name :<b> $lname </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- Address :<b> $address </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- City :<b> $city </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- Country :<b> $country </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- Phone :<b> $phone </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- E-Mail :<b> $email </b> -</div><hr class='style'>
            <div class='css'>- Message :<b> $message -</b></div>

                    </body>
                </html>
    
                " ;
                
if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
        {
            echo 'Your reservation has been sent successfully!';
        }
        
            else
        
        {
            echo 'The message is not sent, could you try again?';
        }

}

?>

<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
alert("Your reservation has been sent successfully!");
window.location.replace("index.html");
</SCRIPT>
<?php
}elseif(strlen($email)<=0){
?>
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
alert("Empty");
window.history.go(-1);
</SCRIPT> 
<?php
}else
{
?>
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
alert("Empty");
window.history.go(-1);
</SCRIPT> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this is the header  
<?php
session_start();
$date = date('Y-m-d');

/////////////////Recuperation variable/////////////////////////////

Comment: Try to `Report not spam` in Gmail

Comment: so nothing is wrong with the code i will try in gmail  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add headers to the email.

```
$mailHeader = "From: hello@yourdomain.com\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Reply-To: hello@yourdomain.com\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Return-Path: hello@yourdomain.com\r\n";
```

You can add CC and BCC as well.

```
$mailHeader .= "CC: sombodyelse@example.com\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "BCC: hidden@example.com\r\n";
```

And then send the email.

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: You can use the ``PhpMailer``  library as well. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: can you add to the code and i will  copy past the code to test and i will change the email thank you  
i m not a developer im only a site owner seeking for help

Comment: there is this header i forget to add it  
<?php
session_start();
$date = date('Y-m-d');

/////////////////Recuperation variable/////////////////////////////